# Package a runnable JPA jar putting persistence.xml outside

Tags: java, jpa, jar

I want to export my jpa/swing project to a runnable jar. But I want the persistence.xml to be outside the jar not packaged inside, so I can change it without the need to export the jar again after each config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JPA specifications, `persistence.xml` file cannot be detected outside the JAR file where the persistence unit is defined. By convention, it should be placed inside `META-INF` directory.

Read JSR-317, paragraph 8.2.1 for more details (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Nevertheless, you can try the hint proposed by this guy [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/109839?start=0&tstart=0) and deploy your archives in exploded form.

Comment: Thx, for the specifications note, but regarding the answer in your link what does the meaning of exploded form.

Comment: It seam it mean to have an application server(exploded form)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I only needed to change Server, database, user and password. So this did it for me:

In JBoss AS, you can even have the property value as a placeholder, for example:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://${DbServer}:1234;databaseName=${DbName}" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${DbUser}" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${DbPassword}" />
```

and then pass the "DbServer", "DbName", "DbUser" and "DbPassword" value as a Java system property:

```
-DDbServer=sql99 -DDbName=db_Name -DDbUser=USER -DDbPassword=pw
```

In Eclipse:

[image: vm args in eclipse]

Comment: The java system property tricks also works for packaged JavaFX applications. The JVM properties are stored in the `app/your-app-name.cfg` file