# presistence.xml not found when using runnable jar

Tags: java, hibernate, executable-jar, persistence.xml, uberjar

I have some troubles running a runnable jar due to

```
HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
```

Directory structure:
[image]

JAR META-INF/Manifest content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Antoniossss
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_40
Main-Class: app.remote.Bootstrap
Class-Path: .
```

Run command from the root:

> java -jar controller-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

This is causing

```
13:19:50.634 [main] DEBUG o.h.b.r.c.i.ClassLoaderServiceImpl - Incoming config yielded no classloaders; adding standard SE ones
13:19:50.637 [main] INFO  o.h.j.b.i.PersistenceXmlParser - HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
13:19:50.638 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Located and parsed 0 persistence units; checking each
13:19:50.638 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Found no matching persistence units
13:19:50.639 [main] DEBUG o.h.b.r.c.i.ClassLoaderServiceImpl - Incoming config yielded no classloaders; adding standard SE ones
13:19:50.639 [main] INFO  o.h.j.b.i.PersistenceXmlParser - HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
13:19:50.639 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Located and parsed 0 persistence units; checking each
13:19:50.640 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Found no matching persistence units
13:19:50.640 [main] DEBUG o.h.b.r.c.i.ClassLoaderServiceImpl - Incoming config yielded no classloaders; adding standard SE ones
13:19:50.641 [main] INFO  o.h.j.b.i.PersistenceXmlParser - HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
13:19:50.641 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Located and parsed 0 persistence units; checking each
13:19:50.643 [main] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Found no matching persistence units
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named registratorPU
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at
```

> META-INF/perstistence.xml is not found

But it is in META-INF dir. Moreover `config.cfg` is read properly, so current dir is indeed in the classpath.

What is strange to me following command runs just fine:

```
java -cp controller-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar; app.remote.Bootstrap
```

But if I remove semicolon(;) after jar name, the error is the same as during jar lunch attempt.

```
java -cp controller-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.remote.Bootstrap
```

Any ideas what is happening here? Jar is created with maven

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.remote.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                              <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in pom.xml

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>path_to_your_resource_folder</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

path_to_your_resource_folderis a path to directory with persistence.xml from your project folder path.
I suggest you to create some directory like src/main/resources and paste persistence.xml here. Then path_to_your_resource_folder= src/main/resources

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. persistence.xml should be external resources so there is no problem to modify it in production environement

Comment: src/main/resources it is a relative path. You don`t need to modify it on prod.

Comment: Ofc you do, as you dont use the same configuration in prod and dev envs. 
src/main/resources will be in compiled into JAR file and this should be outside of the archive.

Comment: yes, it will be inside your jar, and you will publish this jar on production. And you dont need to change this path.

Comment: src/main/resources will be inside of your jar (archive).

Comment: You should keep such resource outside of the jar. And this is what iv wrote in first comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024345/package-a-runnable-jpa-jar-putting-persistence-xml-outside you are not helping.

Comment: But for regular config files, you are half right. It will be perfect if there will be 2 files, inside and outside of jar. Where outside file will override inside file.

Comment: You should better verify your posts you are using as arguments - answer in the link is missleading, as it is not said in JSR that persistance.xml has to be inside JAR only in META-INF (on the classpath/META-INF) and that is a huge difference. Besides, in the answer you can se mention about "exploded" form which means - extracted jar. Here is quote from JSR 8.2.1 : A persistence.xmlfile defines a persistence unit. The persistence.xmlfile is located in the META-INFdirectory of the root of the persistence unit.
Nothinig about beeing inside JAR. Im not helping, and you are missleading.

Comment: My answer says how exactly you can fix the problem, but you can add an answer with description, how to add external resources to classpath and suggestion to put persistence.xml there. Please add all details in your answer, for not to be misleading.